# How to Modify Search REST query after Thesaurus is called

Tags: 2013, rest, enterprise-search

I have a query

> "< my_url >/_api/search/query?querytext="Bureau'"

I have added to the Thesaurus **Bureau,Office**. I am trying to get the query to return everything that 'Office*' would return. However, I cannot just do `Bureau*` because then the Thesaurus does not activate.

I know that I can just add **Bureau,Office_of_A**,  **Bureau,Office_of_B**, etc. to the Thesaurus but I have a long list with multiple words and I cannot do every possible combination.

is there a way to call the Thesaurus but add the * to the query?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an answer to this question anywhere on the internet.
Eventually, I was forced to create my own pseudo thesaurus. The SharePoint Thesaurus ended up being just too limited in its use.